# jQuery array in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, jqplot

Hello everyone I have a small question about array in array and how to call it...
EX:

```
var plotName = ['bearShevaPlot', 'haifaPlot', 'tiberiasPlot', 'kfarSabaPlot', 'netanyaPlot', 'rishonLezionPlot', 'rehovotPlot', 'telAvivPlot'];
var chartName = ['bearShevaCity', 'haifaCity', 'tiberiasCity', 'kfarSabaCity', 'netanyaCity', 'rishonLezionCity', 'rehovotCity', 'telAvivCity'];
```

to call all of the array and preform a function on each of them i'll use .each jQuery function.

```
$.each(plotName,function(cName,pName){
     chartName[cName];
     var pName = $.jqplot(''+chartName[cName]+'', [/* another var */], {
          //my code here
     });
});
```

Now because i need to have a 3rd var I want to have an array inside an array like:

```
var plotName = [['bearShevaPlot', 'bearSheva'], ['haifaPlot', 'haifa'], ['tiberiasPlot', 'tiberias'], ['kfarSabaPlot', 'kfarSaba'], ['netanyaPlot', 'netanya'], ['rishonLezionPlot', 'rishonLezion'], ['rehovotPlot', 'rehovot'], ['telAvivPlot', 'telAviv']];
```

and my question is how can i call "bearSheva" which is the second val of the first array inside the array.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firstPlot` & `secondPlot` will have the desired values.

```
var chartName = ['bearShevaCity', 'haifaCity', 'tiberiasCity', 'kfarSabaCity', 'netanyaCity', 'rishonLezionCity', 'rehovotCity', 'telAvivCity'];
var plotName = [['bearShevaPlot', 'bearSheva'], ['haifaPlot', 'haifa'], ['tiberiasPlot', 'tiberias'], ['kfarSabaPlot', 'kfarSaba'], ['netanyaPlot', 'netanya'], ['rishonLezionPlot', 'rishonLezion'], ['rehovotPlot', 'rehovot'], ['telAvivPlot', 'telAviv']];

$.each(plotName,function(cName,pName){
     var chart = chartName[cName];
     var firstPlot = pName[0];
     var secondPlot = pName[1];
     var pName = $.jqplot(''+chartName[cName]+'', [/* another var */], {
          //my code here
     });
});
```

Hope it helps.